# Redirect requests to all urls but one with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with only a wordpress(let's call it blog) application in it. I now need to add another web app(let's call it portfolio) to the same domain and will move the blog to site.com/blog. The user will be able to choose which one to visit on the splash page. So basically I will have the following structure:

```
site.com -> splash page
site.com/blog
site.com/portfolio
```

The thing is, I don't want to break the existing links across the web to the blog posts and want to 301 redirect all requests that are not for /portfolio to the blog app, for example:

```
site.com/about_me redirects to site.com/wordpress/about_me but
site.com/portfolio/index doesn't get redirected.
```

I guess it's done inside the .htaccess file but after much reading couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` to match `portfolio` and act on non-matching requests:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if it isn't a real existing file (like img or css)
# Remove these two lines if your images and CSS break on the wordpress site.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite (redirect 301) requests not already to portfolio or wordpress to /wordpress
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(portfolio|wordpress)
RewriteRule ^(.*) wordpress/$1 [L,R=301]
```